# meaning of "to return our gaze"

Tags: meaning

> *He interprets Les Fleurs du mal as reflecting the desintegration of the material world's aura, the symbolic associations that once permitted sacred objects **to return our gaze**.*

I hesitate how to understand the phrase "to return our gaze" in the context of the sentence. Do you think that it means that secret objects enebles us to see in more – let's say spiritual – way. Or it simply means that the secret objects are put before our eyes by the means of associations of Les Fleurs.

Source: M. LILLA, The Reckless Mind, p. 105.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to "return someone's gaze" is to look back at them when they are looking at you. "Bob stared at Mary. She turned, saw him watching her, and returned his gaze."

I'm not quite sure what the writer of this quote is trying to say without reading more context. He is saying that in the past people believed that sacred objects would look back when we looked at them, but now they don't. I'd guess he means that people used to believe that these objects had consciousness or awareness, but now we see them as just inanimate objects.

Comment: I can't really say without reading the broader context. I THINK the "symbolic assocation" relates back to "aura", and not "du mal". I think "du mal" is French for "bad" or "trouble", but exactly what "Les Fleur's du mal" is I have no idea. But the "symbolic associations" probably aren't the bad thing, but the aura.

Comment: Les Fleurs du mal is The Flowers of Evil, the book of poetry written by Baudelaire.

Comment: @bart-leby Ah, I totally mis-read that. This just re-redoubles the part of my answer that says "I can't really say".

Answer (score 0):

For something to *return your gaze* (literally, *look right back into your eyes*), it effectively has to either *be*, or *appear to be* "sentient" (to have a mind, and be aware of both you and it as conscious beings).

So in OP's specific context, it's being asserted that sacred objects once had (but have now lost) the symbolic associations that enabled us to "personify, anthropomorphize", say, an image/statue of Jesus or Mary in such a way that we can believe it really *is* that "person". So it can "talk" to us (perhaps "telepathically"), or "look" into our eyes.

Comment: [And when you gaze long into an abyss the abyss also gazes into you.](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche) I don't know that it implies sentience so much as the ability to affect your soul.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't say no-one would *ever* speak of an abyss "returning their gaze", but it would be an *extremely* figurative / poetic usage. To a first approximation, anything capable of returning your gaze must have *eyes*, and at least some level of *sentience*. I suspect the reason you think in terms of "ability to affect your soul" is because if you were prepared to speak of, say, your teddy bear "returning your gaze", that would be because you related to the stuffed toy in a very *personal,* (moving, even *spiritual*) way (somewhat like a real-life interactive "friend").

Comment: To tell the truth I am now a little bit lost in the meaning of the sentence. I thought that "symbolic associations" are related to Baudelaire's The Flowers of Evil but the occurence of the word  "once" questions it.

Comment: I have it ! It is "aura" to which associations are related. Now it makes sense…

Comment: @bart-leby: I can't access the surrounding context of OP's cited text, but from what we have it seems pretty clear to me we're talking about the "associations" *of sacred objects* (but I suppose feasibly it could be just the more generic associations we used to have in matters of religion and "spirituality").

Comment: I see your point about the abyss and the figurative gaze. An object doesn't have to be sentient to return your gaze; it just has to have open eyes (or at least one eye-like thing). I can stare at a goldfish and talk about it "returning my gaze", but I don't necessarily believe it is self-aware. Maybe I let it be for the purposes of symbolizing something else. I'm not necessarily disagreeing with your explanation, it just seems narrow. Can eyes tattooed on someone's back return our gaze? An empty mask?